# How can Jenkins autostart a VirtualBox slave?

Tags: jenkins, virtualbox, autostart

I have a VirtualBox Jenkins slave. I start it manually every time it goes down (e.g. after doing reboot to the PC).

Is there a way to make Jenkins start it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a **Windows** host that should run an **Ubuntu 14.04** virtual machine Jenkins slave.

Pre-requirements: you should have a VM slave defined in Jenkins (http://YOUR-JENKINS-URL/computer/)

This is how I solved it:

1) Setup Ubuntu VM to automatically start a service on boot that runs a script to start Jenkins slave:

- Use [upstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto) to run the script: create a the file  /etc/init/jenkins-slave.conf

  ```
  description "A job to start a Jenkins slave"
  author "Your Name"
  start on runlevel [2345]
  exec echo Starting Jenkins slave at `date` >> /var/log/jenkins-slave-job.log
  exec /jenkins/run.sh
  ```
- The /jenkins/run.sh:

  ```
  cd $(dirname $0)
  java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl         
  http://YOUR-JENKINS-URL/computer/NAME-OF-NODE/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 51d080f68b3d2552c977840aa8a01bb371a1b3e8b3326f36fadb497e597185ce
  ```
- The /Jenkins folder should contain slave.jar file downloaded from Jenkins node page.
- The 2 last lines in the run.sh file should be taken from the Jenkins node page.

2) Setup Windows to start the VM on startup:

- Create a Windows shourtcut with the following value in the "Target:"

  ```
  "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm "UbuntuVBox"
  ```
- Where UbuntuVBox should be replaced with the name of your VM
- Put the shortcut under "Startup" folder in the Windows start menu

**To conclude:**

After doing the above steps - if you reboot the Windows host, it should run the shortcut, that will run the VM. The VM will run the service "Jenkins-slave" and your Jenkins slave should be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Yes, we can do it.

Just add VitrualBox as a service in your PC, and add Jenkins Slave as an service in that VitrualBox VM.

**Long answer:**

In fact, we are talking about two things here:

1. how to auto-start a VirtualBox VM when the host of VirtualBox is restarted.
2. how to auto-start a jenkins slave when this node client is restarted.

Or , in another word , we are talking one thing:

3. how to auto-start some stuff when computer restarted.

But the detail operations related to the OS you are using.
(For windows, this tool may help: https://nssm.cc/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [VirtualBox Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/VirtualBox+Plugin) that:

- starts VMs automatically when needed
- stops VMs when no longer needed

It requires *VirtualBox web service* (vboxwebsrv) to control VMs (see e.g. [chapter 9.12 of the VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html) to get it running).

Comment: Is there a newer plugin that supports latest VirtualBox ?

Comment: @ArcinB Plugin seems to have been updated with VirtualBox 6 support. See the latest commits [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/virtualbox-plugin). Some of its [forks](https://github.com/jenkinsci/virtualbox-plugin/network) also mention VirtualBox 6 support. I no longer use this plugin so can't help any more...